# How to separate links for (bootstrap,jquery,css,js) in separate file and attch file link in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, optimization, hyperlink

I am making a simple website using (HTML ,CSS, Bootstrap, JavaScript, JQuery).My question's are:

1. How I separate all links or scripts tag in a separate file and then include this file in my index.html?
2. How I can make bootstrap globally accessible to all my project files?

Because without it my **head tag** is messed up and I want to write clean code.

Comment: `<head>` is meant to have `scripts` or `css` link styles url. What do you mean by messed  up ?

Comment: i have about 10 to 12 links are they are looking not good for me.i want to separate them in a single file.and used the link of that file

Answer (score -1):

- It cannot done in pure html If you are using any template-engine you can do so.
- If you want you can do it using JavaScript But it's not a good practice to do so.

  - Make a file tags.txt put all tags there and then
  - Use fetch to fetch the file and put it into html with javascript

```js
fetch('/tags.txt').then(res => {
        res.text().then(data => {
          console.log(data)
          document.querySelector('head').html = data ;
        })
      })
```

Comment: if you are using template engine then go to docs and search for how to include an file